# Unable to produce messages using kafka producer with dot net

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, confluent-kafka-dotnet

I am trying to implement kafka producer and consumer with dot net running through docker but it is not producing messages to topic and giving this error....my broker is running and even I am able to implement the same in cmd but not through dot net console app

```
%3|1684755847.168|FAIL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:kafka:9092/1001]: kafka:9092/1001: Connect to ipv4#172.104.101.12:9092 failed: Unknown error (after 23388ms in state CONNECT)
%3|1684755847.170|ERROR|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:app]: rdkafka#producer-1: kafka:9092/1001: Connect to ipv4#172.104.101.12:9092 failed: Unknown error (after 23388ms in state CONNECT)
```

```
using Confluent.Kafka;
using Newtonsoft.Json;



namespace KafkaProducer
{
    class Program
    {
        //private const string BootstrapServers = "localhost:9092";
        private const string Topic = "foo-too";



        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var config = new ProducerConfig
            {
                BootstrapServers = "localhost:9092"
            };



            using (var producer = new ProducerBuilder<Null, string>(config).Build())
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter a message (or 'exit' to quit):");
                    var message = Console.ReadLine();



                    if (message == "exit")
                        break;



                    var messageValue = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message);
                    var result = await producer.ProduceAsync(Topic, new Message<Null, string> { Value = messageValue });



                    Console.WriteLine($"Message delivered to {result.TopicPartitionOffset}");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

here is my docker compose

```yaml
---
version: '3.4'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-server
    hostname: broker
    container_name: broker
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://192.168.1.1:9092
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_LICENSE_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONFLUENT_SUPPORT_CUSTOMER_ID: 'anonymous'
```

Comment: If your C# code is also running in a container, then you need to use `broker:29092` as your bootstrap servers, as the linked post says. Otherwise, it's not clear to me how/why your logs say `kafka:9092` when `kafka` hostname is mentioned nowhere in your code/config